# How do I modify my post condition to achieve Gold standard of Spark proof - Ada SPARK

Tags: computer-science, ada, formal-methods, spark-ada

I am totally new to Ada, and have been trying to implement some basics. I have a simple function to flip a coin - not randomly, heads should be flipped to tails and vice versa. I added a post condition that flip(coin) != coin. It is supposed to say that a flipped coin must not equal the original coin, but when I try to prove the file with --mode gold, I get the following warnings:

```
flip_coin.ads:8:06: warning: postcondition does not mention function result
flip_coin.ads:8:14: warning: call to "flip" within its postcondition will lead to infinite recursion
flip_coin.ads:8:14: medium: postcondition might fail, cannot prove flip(x) /= x[#0]
```

Here is the ads file

```
package flip_coin with SPARK_Mode
is
  type Coin is (Heads, Tails);

  function flip (x : Coin) return Coin with
   Post => flip(x) /= x;
end flip_coin;
```

And here is the .adb file

```
package body flip_coin with SPARK_Mode
is

  function flip (x : Coin) return Coin
  is
  begin
    if x = Heads then return Tails; else return Heads; end if;
  end flip;

end flip_coin;
```

Any help would be great! I will be asking plenty more over the next 2 weeks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the postcondition:

```
function flip (x : Coin) return Coin with
   Post => flip'Result /= x;
```

This ensures that the function result does not equal the function input `x`.

Stating `flip(x)` in your postcondition will indeed result in infinite recursion as the postcondition will be checked for each invocation of `flip`. As a result, the function will always be evaluated one more time to check the postcondition: infinite recursion.

Comment: Perfect Thanks! I tried flip'Result(x) /= x which didn't work and now I know why. amazing!